# Pennsylvania mail in return rates 2023 primary?

Tags: united-states, voting, primaries, pennsylvania

In Pennsylvania, there is a municipal primary happening with Election Day on May 16. I have not been able to find data on Pennsylvania's mail request data but I have a feeling it exists because such data was presented for the 2022 midterms.

If such data is available, how many mail ballots were returned and requested statewide, and what was the partisanship breakdown?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are asking about finding data for an election that has yet to occur. This data is unlikely to be present in any form until after the election is complete. Mail in ballots can be requested until May 9th and they can be returned until May 16th meaning it is impossible to have this data until after the election.

Comment: That is false there is election data about this kind of thing in many US elections it's just votes cast aren't available

Comment: But you specifically ask for things like how many ballots were returned that cannot be known now. Nobody can answer the question until at least May 16. Afterwards the question can be answered although I guess that the source of information if it exists is similar to that of past elections. Where is the data of past elections published?

Comment: There is data about how many mail in ballots are requested and returned when people are still able to request and return ballots?

Comment: I truly do not understand the rationale for closing this question. If the information will not be available until May 17th, then there will be no answer until May 17th. To say that the question is off-topic today, but will be on-topic on May 17th, is incongruous. Who among the close voters will return on May 17th to re-open the question? If a web page is currently available with regular updates, an answer may still be given today, allowing the OP to follow the progress as desired.

Comment: @RickSmith I'm not 100% sure that the answer will be available on May 16 and I'm not terribly insisting on closing now and returning later but at the very least this question is premature. There won't be any meaningful answer until at least 2 and a half week, however the question creator seems to think there might be one possible. That may hint that something about the question is also not clear enough. Which information exactly is requested? Also if it was available last time for the last election, why not wait and search in that similar place first?

Comment: I agree that it is largely premature as it related to something that hasn't happened yet. It may be ripe for reopening when the election has occurred. FWIW, I am also inclined to think that Politics.SE in not an appropriate place for breaking coverage of election turnout rates as it happens.

Comment: This should be reopened because it CAN be answered with sources available to the public. However it should then be closed again due to a stunning lack of research. Pennsylvania has a board of elections that has a website. On the website is a button for daily report of absentee ballots. https://www.vote.pa.gov/About-Elections/Pages/Election-Results.aspx

Comment: @RickSmith: I'm VTC this because the answer will change day-by-day, until the day of the election. So it is "unclear what the OP is asking", as to which day's answer is correct. If the Q is only about a data source, that's slightly different. If he wants a graph over time, that's also a bit different. But "how many mail ballots were returned and requested statewide" is not asking for either of those (latter two).

Comment: @Damila: And which day's answer is the correct one? (That XLSX file changes every day, according to the description on that page.) Also the DL button doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Fizz you are correct. I thought the question was “where can one find…” but as written it is “what is the number…” that number will indeed change each day until it’s all done. So the answer would be “click on this website for your answer at that time.”

Comment: Voting to close as your immediate intent is not clear - Do you want to know whether the data exists and want the 2022 data? Or do you only want the 2023 data (which is not yet available) or both 2022 and 2023 data. Please edit and update your answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

The question would be better if it asked “where can one find the data on…”. As discussed in the comments, as written the answer to your question is either “no one knows because it did not happen yet” or “here are the numbers and when someone looks tomorrow they will be inaccurate.”

That said, the data you want with requested, sent, returned by party affiliation and county can be downloaded as an .xlsx on https://www.vote.pa.gov/About-Elections/Pages/Election-Results.aspx

Scroll down and click on “Daily Mail Ballot Report”. Despite the name, it has tabs for total, mail in, and absentee.

As the PA Board of Elections themselves describe it:

> This point-in-time transactional data is being published for informational purposes to provide a high-level overview of the processing of absentee and mail-in ballots by county election offices. This data is pulled once per day from the Statewide Uniform Registry of Electors (SURE system) and it reflects activity recorded by the counties in the SURE system as of the time of the pull.